# How to fix drop-down menu with multi nesting? Vanila JS

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

How to fix multi nesting drop-down (arrow and padding-left)?

Look [code on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oKLpbX)
**Logic**:
   if the dropdown expanded arrow goes left and the text moves with the padd_left class (padding-left show : 70px) . 
It does not work for me somewhere. I don't know reason. 
If some part is not clear to you, ask me.
Propertly workflow is when click on "Wer bildet den Staat?"  menu and dropdown set `padding-left: 70px` and arrow set in left side when is expanded.
In this image I provide how is good example and how is not:
https://ibb.co/4FkdMJS

HTML:

```html
<section class="section section-two">
  <div class="header-holder">
    <h3>Startseite</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper wrapper-two">
    <div class="first-div-holder">
      <div class="first-lower-div">
        <div class="low-lower">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn dropbtn-one">
                Staatskunde Grundbegriffe
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <ul>
                <li class="item-has-children">
                  <a href="#0" class="padd-left"> Wer bildet den Staat?  <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#0" class="padd-left">Staatsanschauungen im Wandel der
                        Jahrhunderte   <span class="rightt">  </span> <span
                              >  </span></a>

                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <!--sub-menu with sub-cutegory-->
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/erste-lebensgemeinschaften.html">Erste
                                                    Lebensgemeinschaften </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/vom-gottkönig-zur-demokratie.html">Vom Gottkönig zur Demokratie<span
                                                        >  </span></a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/rom–vom-stadtstaat-zur-grossmacht.html">Rom – Vom Stadtstaat zur
                                                    Grossmacht </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/gottesgnadentum–kirchliche-und-weltliche-macht.html">Gottesgnadentum – Kirchliche und weltliche
                                                    Macht </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/die-reformation-und-die-politischen-folgen.html">Die Reformation und die politischen Folgen
                                                </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/wege-zum-modernen-staat.html">Wege zum modernen Staat </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/das-zeitalter-des-bürgertums.html">Das Zeitalter des Bürgertums </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/die-beiden-weltkriege.html">Die beiden Weltkriege </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/die-zeit-nach-1945.html">Die Zeit nach 1945 </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/staatsanschauungen-heute.html">Staatsanschauungen heute </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Staatsanschauungen-im Wandel-der-Jahrhunderte/multikulturelle-gesellschaft.html">Multikulturelle Gesellschaft </a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/grundlagen-des-usammenlebens-einzelner-gruppen.html">Grundlagen des Zusammenlebens einzelner Gruppen </a></li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/der-staat-ordnet-die-beziehungen.html">Der Staat ordnet die Beziehungen
                                        </a></li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="#0">Die Rolle des Volkes im politischen System<span
                                                class="rightt">  </span></a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <!--sub-menu with sub-cutegory-->
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Die-Rolle-des Volkes-im-politischen-System/volk-und-herrschaft.html">Volk und Herrschaft </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Wer-bildet-den-Staat/Die-Rolle-des Volkes-im-politischen-System/die-ausübung-politischer-rechte.html">Die Ausübung politischer Rechte<span
                                                >  </span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <div class="hr2"></div>
                <li class="item-has-children">
                  <a href="#0" class="padd-left">Voraussetzungen zur Staatsbildung <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="Voraussetzungen-zur-Staatsbildung/was-gehört-zu-einem-staatsgebiet.html">Was gehört zu einem
                                            Staatsgebiet?
                                        </a></li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="Voraussetzungen-zur-Staatsbildung/vom-absolutismus-zur-gewaltentrennung.html">Vom Absolutismus
                                            zur Gewaltentrennung </a></li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="Voraussetzungen-zur-Staatsbildung/wer-gehört-zum-staat.html">Wer gehört zum
                                            Staat?</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <div class="hr2"></div>
                <li class="item-has-children">
                  <a href="#0" class="padd-left">Staats- und Regierungsformen <span class="rightt">  </span></a>
                  <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#0">Staats- und Regierungsformen <span class="rightt">
                                        </span></a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <!--sub-menu with sub-cutegory-->
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Staats-un-Regierungsformen/die-klassische-einteilung-in-griechenland.html">Die
                                                    klassische Einteilung in Griechenland </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Staats-un-Regierungsformen/die-einteilung-nach%20den-heutigen-politischen-verhältnissen.html">Die Einteilung nach den heutigen politischen Verhältnissen<span
                                                >  </span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="#0">Monarchie und Republik <span class="rightt">
                                        </span></a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <!--sub-menu with sub-cutegory-->
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Monarchie-und-Republik/absolute-und-konstitutionelle-monarchie.html">Absolute
                                                    und konstitutionelle Monarchie </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Monarchie-und-Republik/republik.html"> Republik<span
                                                >  </span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="#0">Einheitsstaat und Bundesstaat <span class="rightt">
                                        </span></a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <!--sub-menu with sub-cutegory-->
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Einheitsstaat-und-Bundesstaat/einheitsstaat-oder-zentralstaat.html">Einheitsstaat oder Zentralstaat </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Einheitsstaat-und-Bundesstaat/bundesstaat-oder-föderalistischer-staat.html"> Bundesstaat oder föderalistischer Staat<span
                                                >  </span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/staatenbund-oder-konföderation.html">Staatenbund oder
                                            Konföderation</a></li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="#0">Nationalstaat und Nationalitätenstaat <span
                                                class="rightt">  </span></a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <!--sub-menu with sub-cutegory-->
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Nationalstaat-und-Nationalitätenstaat/nationalstaat.html">Einheitsstaat oder Zentralstaat </a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Nationalstaat-und-Nationalitätenstaat/nationalitätenstaat.html"> Bundesstaat oder föderalistischer Staat<span
                                                >  </span></a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <div class="hr2"></div>
                    <li><a href="#0">Demokratie und Diktatur<span class="rightt">
                                        </span></a>
                      <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <!--sub-menu with sub-cutegory-->
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Demokratie-und-Diktatur/repräsentanten-der-macht.html">Repräsentanten der Macht</a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Demokratie-und-Diktatur/demokratie.html">
                                                    Demokratie<span
                                                >  </span></a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                        <li><a href="Staats-un-Regierungsformen/Demokratie-und-Diktatur/diktatur.html">
                                                    Diktatur</a></li>
                        <div class="hr2"></div>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

CSS-SCSS:

```
$facebookBlue: #153161;
$strongRed: #9a0000;
$strongYellow: #ee8f01;
$white: #ffffff;
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "Lato", "Arial", sans-serif !important;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    .hr {
        margin: 40px auto;
        height: 1px;
        background: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid $white;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
    .section {
        padding-bottom: 80px;
    }
    .text-holder {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -100px; left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        text-align: center;

        h1 {
            color: $facebookBlue;
        }
    }

    .arr-arrow {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 6px;
        height: 6px;
        cursor: pointer;
        // transform: translateY(-30%);
        &:after {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            width: 6px;
            height: 6px;
            border-top: 2px solid black;
            border-right: 2px solid black;
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
            display: flex;

        }
    }
}
 .dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    .dropbtn {
        background-color: $facebookBlue;
        color: $white;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 600;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        height: 55px;
        background: #153161;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
        padding: 12px 50px;
        position: relative;
        width: 360px;
        text-align: left;
        i {
            margin-left: 30px;
            color: #8391ab;
            // opacity: 0.2;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            right: 25px;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
        }
        .arrow {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-left: 10px solid transparent;
            border-right: 10px solid transparent;
            border-top: 10px solid #8191aa;
            margin: 100%;
            padding-top: 4px;
            z-index: 999;
        }
    }

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    // position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 330px;
    z-index: 999;
    a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 25px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 100%;
        &:hover {
            background-color: #F8F8F8
        }
    }
    .rightt {
        display: inline-block;
        // width: 9px;
        // height: 9px;
        cursor: pointer;
        // padding-left: 180px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: 999;
        &:after {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            width: 9px;
            height: 9px;
            border-top: 0.2em solid #ababab;
            border-right: 0.2em solid #ababab;
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
    }
    .left {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        z-index: 999;
        &:after {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            width: 29px;
            height: 29px;
            border-top: 0.2em solid #ababab;
            border-right: 0.2em solid #ababab;
            -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
    }
    .item-has-children {
        a {
            position: relative;
        }
    }
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    background: white;
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

.sub-menu.selected {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.rightt.selected {
    left: 40px;
    top: 25%;
    right: auto;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.padd-left {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.padd-left.selected {
    padding-left: 70px;
}

.section-two {
    padding: 0 30px;
    .header-holder {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 40px 0px;
        h3 {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: 'Replica Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #666;
        }
    }
    .wrapper-two {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        .first-div-holder {
            background: brown;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .first-lower-div {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            .low-lower {
                p {
                    color: white;
                }
            }
            @media (max-width: 1150px) { 
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                width: 100%;
              }
              @media (max-width: 450px) { 
                div:nth-child(1) {
                    display: flex;
                    max-width: 250px!important;
                }
              }
        }
        .second-lower-div {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 150px;

            @media (max-width: 600px) {
                padding: unset;
            }
            h1 {
                font-size: 80px;
                color: $white;
            }
            h4 {
                font-size: 30px;
                margin-top: -50px;
                color: $white;
            }
        }
        .third-lower-div {
            display: flex;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            text-align: right;
            justify-content: center;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            .bottom-lower {
                display: flex;
                align-content: center;
                &:nth-child(1),
                &:nth-child(2),
                &:nth-child(3),
                &:nth-child(4) {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    color: $white;
                }
            }
            p {
                color: $white;
                font-weight: 600;
                font-size: 16px;
                margin: 0 10px;
            }
            @media (max-width: 700px) { 
                flex-direction: column;
                align-items: center;
                width: 100%;
              }
        }
        .second-div-holder {
            background: #f1f1f1; 
            .second-div-holder-div {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: center;
                padding: 15px; 
                .div-column {
                    flex: 1;
                    min-width: 30%;
                    padding: 25px;
                    overflow: hidden;
                    // for small device 
                    // flex: 0 0 100%;
                    // max-width: 100%;
                    @media (max-width: 600px) {  
                        min-width: 100%!important;

                      }
                      @media (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 600px)  {  
                        min-width: 50%!important;
                      }

                    .div-column-first {
                        height: 210px;

                        img {
                            height: 100%;
                            width: 100%;
                            object-fit: cover;
                        }
                        #first-child-image {
                            border-bottom: 5px solid $facebookBlue;
                        }
                        #second-child-image {
                            border-bottom: 5px solid $strongRed;
                        }
                        #third-child-image {
                            border-bottom: 5px solid $strongYellow;
                        }
                    }
                    .div-column-second {
                        padding: 40px;
                        background: $white;
                        text-align: center;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JS:

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".item-has-children");
const padd_left = document.querySelectorAll(".padd-left"); 
links.forEach((link) => {
  link.addEventListener('click', (e) => { 
    const index = Array.from(links).indexOf(link)
    if (e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.contains('selected')) {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('selected') 
      e.target.querySelector('.rightt').classList.remove('selected');
      Array.from(padd_left)[index].classList.remove('selected')
    } else {
      e.target.nextElementSibling.classList.add('selected')
      e.target.querySelector('.rightt').classList.add('selected');
      Array.from(padd_left)[index].classList.add('selected')
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you make a minimal example that shows the issue you are having? The larger the code snippets, the less likely someone will have time to dig through it. You posted 26 KB of code. That's a lot ;)

Comment: Probably problem is on javascript file..
But i don't know where

Comment: It is very unlikely, that you need 26 KB to demonstrate the problem. Try reducing the code you have, including HTML, CSS, JS code... until it is reduced to fit into one screen or less. At one point you fill spot the problem yourself, or will be able to post reduced code here, so someone can help. Good luck with learning to code!

Comment: I try to complete explain problem

Comment: Remove absolute from your arrow. Place it before your text and maybe give it position: relative with a left:-5px to give it more space

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Seems that `Array.from(padd_left)[index]` returns different element than you expect for elements different than "Wer bildet den Staat?"